Invoking function in Julia from Javascript using Electron.jl
I am trying to build a simple Electron app using Julia as my back-end language and HTML/CSS/Javascript as front-end by means of the Electron.jl package. Essentially, I have written a CVM structure on the back-end to handle data from my SQLite database, which I want to communicate to the front-end in order to display (sufficient for now). I am aware that you can run Javascript functions in Julia, but cannot figure out how to request the data on the back-end from Javascript. As you may notice, I am not the most advanced user of these languages (I have only self-taught knowledge of front-end development and some shallow work experience), so please excuse me if I asked a preposterous question.
I have tried to add
win.webContents.executeJavaScript("const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron'); function callJulia(name, ...args) { ipcRenderer.send('ipc-message', name, ...args); }; global['callJulia'] = callJulia;undefined")

to the existing snippets in Electron.jl:
win.webContents.on("did-finish-load", function() {
        win.webContents.executeJavaScript("const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron'); function sendMessageToJulia(message) { ipcRenderer.send('msg-for-julia-process', message); }; global['sendMessageToJulia'] = sendMessageToJulia;undefined")
    })

However, the function was not recognized in Javascript when I tried to use it. I must say this was mainly the suggestion of ChatGPT, whose 'expertise' in this niche is rather unhelpful.
Thank you in advance!

I'm still confused as to what you're trying to do

@ZachJensz in sum, I want to request the data from my SQLite database using existing Julia functions from Javascript. So, say I have the function “function get(db::SQLite.db, id::Integer)” in Julia, I would like to construct a method where I can call this function in Javascript and display the data in the HTML.
